# nginx throws cannot get / bad gateway when trying to connect to proxypass path

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, proxypass

I created a proxypass on my nginx server, and enabled ssl on it, but with and without ssl I still get an error saying 502 bad gateway. What can I fix to resolve this?(p.s. when I use curl on localhost 6060, it returns the correct html, so I know that works, however when I curl the url it redirects to, it throws `Cannot GET /iwl`)

Nginx conf:
`location /iwl {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:6060;
   proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
   proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
}`

Error log:
`2019/01/17 12:29:57 [error] 1575#1575: *7 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: mysite.com, request: "GET /iwl HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:6060/iwl", host: "mysite.com"`

Comment: please post the entire nginx config

Comment: The issue slightly changed, sorry. do you still need the full conf?

Comment: The question should reflect the current issue.  Do you still need an answer?  If not, you can post a solution to your own problem as an answer.  Regarding the nginx config it's always good to see the surrounding code as the fault could lie outwith the code you posted.  Anyone trying to solve needs to see the full context.  At a guess I would say try a trailing slash on the `proxy_pass` line so: `http://localhost:6060/;`

Comment: it worked... wow. a trailing slash was all I needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a trailing slash on the `proxy_pass` line of your nginx config:

```
location /iwl {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:6060/;
   proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
   proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
}
```

Comment: Sorry to nag you like this, but I changed my conf, and it does work, however, none of the scripts load in `location /iwl {
                root /home/ubuntu/noderoot/;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:6060/;
                proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/jakesandbox.com/fullchain.pem;
                proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        }` see the script error for yourself: https://jakesandbox.com/iwl I figured this would be a comon second error, so I decided to tack this on. Just check the console to see the script loading errors

Comment: @Jaket It would probably be worth creating a separate question for the script error, and include the entire nginx conf, as well as references to what 'script' is failing: is it PHP or something else, along with errors.

Comment: alright, new thread coming up.